# Underline not working in Sublime Text 2 theme

Tags: themes, sublimetext2

I'm using [ST2 build 2217](http://www.sublimetext.com/) on OSX 10.8.2. Everything else works great, except I can't get underlining to work. Here's an example from my theme file:

```xml
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Language Constant</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>constant.language</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string>bold italic underline</string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#FF1308</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

In ST2, a Python language constant like ***`True`*** or ***`False`*** shows up in red with bolded italic text, like expected, but not underlined like it would show up in [TextMate](http://www.macromates.com). It doesn't matter the language or context, I can't get underlining to work. The only thing that does work is bracket matching, which does show a thin underline for matching pairs. Any suggestions?

Comment: It may not be supported, thoguh I'm no expert at the theme stuff. You may want to ask on the ST forums [link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/). I think more ST users look there than here.

Comment: @skuroda I posted there over a week ago, nobody's answered...

Comment: Ah ok, sorry to hear that. I just did a test in ST3 (W7), but there doesn't appear to be an underline. Next best thing would be to make a feature request I suppose.

Comment: I concur with @skuroda - underline didn't work for me in version 2 or 3, so I'd assume it's not implemented fully.

Comment: @skuroda - Put that in an official answer and you'll get my bounty...

Comment: Not sure when you get notified of updates to your post, so I'll comment here to (I'm pretty sure you will get it). See my edited post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be supported, thoguh I'm no expert at the theme stuff. You may want to ask on the ST forums ([link](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/)). I think more ST users look there than here.

I just did a test in ST3 (W7), but there doesn't appear to be an underline. Next best thing would be to make a feature request I suppose.

Edit:

I've updated my plugin ([link](https://github.com/skuroda/PersistentRegexHighlight)) to underline. If you have any issues, create an issue on the github page. A bit of a warning though, it's not the most efficient plugin (something I need to improve on), so if you have large files, there will probably be some performance degradation.

[image: Sample]

Answer (score 2):

You can try this hack if you don't mind the additional overhead

```
  # To underline a region, we use a "hack" specific to SublimeText
  # where we create a list of empty regions for each character
  # which we want to underline.  When drawing with
  # sublime.DRAW_EMPTY_AS_OVERWRITE, such empty regions
  # will appear as underlined.

  line = view.full_line(view.text_point(lineno, 0))
  position += line.begin()

  for i in xrange(length):
     underline.append(sublime.Region(position + i))
```

Comment: Where would I put this? Also, how does this mesh with my theme in highlighting certain scopes?

Comment: Hmm, didn't think of trying to use regions to do it. Though, I didn't realize selecting a single point for a region would create an underline. You would basically write a plugin that utilizes view.add_regions. You can specify a scope there to color the underline. If you just want to highlight constants, it shouldn't be to bad. I wrote a plugin to highlight regex patterns. I bet I could tweak it some to optionally underline them.

Answer (score 1):

From what little I've been able to find, it looks like underline just hasn't been implemented in ST2 or ST3 yet. I've submitted a [feature request](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/153925-implement-underline-as-part-of-fontstyle-in-tmtheme/) on userecho, so we'll see where that goes. Vote for it if you'd like this feature, too!